# global variables and .format()

Tags: python, pandas, string.format

I wrote a python script that generates PDF reports. I had to do some data manipulation to change column names in each of the data sets I used.

My question is, Is there a way to set a global variable and then using .format() inside the `Target_Hours_All.rename()` ???

I have hardcoded each column name.

For example, `Target_Hours_All.rename(columns = {'VP_x':'VP', '2018 Q1 Target Hours':'hourTarget18Q1'}, inplace = True)`

However, I want to be able to run this each quarter without having to update every `df.rename`. Instead, I would like to have global variables at the top of the script and change those.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Even better: have the script accept the value from the command line or the environment? Anyway, it's as simple as passing the variable instead of your hand-written string. `bar = 'Timothy'; 'hello {foo}'.format(foo=bar)`

Comment: @spectras, Already ahead of ya! I'm using `argparse` for that. So, just like `current_year = 2018` then `Target_Hours_All.rename(columns = {'VP_x':'VP', '2018 Q1 Target Hours':'hourTarget18Q1'.format(hourTarget18Q1=current_year}, inplace = True)`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way? Move the strings you want to change out of the function call into variables and then use the variables within Target_Hours_All.rename()
This makes the code way lot easier to read.

I can only guess what Target_Hours_All.rename does. But my guess would be that it takes the hash in "columns" and replaces the key with the value. Correct?

So could write your columns line as:

```
columns = {}
vpl = 'VP_x'
vpr = 'VP'
columns[vpl] = vpr
target_hours_l = '20{year} {quarter} Target Hours'.format(year='18', quarter='Q1')
target_hours_r = 'hourTarget{year}{quarter}'.format(year='18',quarter='Q1')
columns[target_hours_l] = target_hours_r
Target_Hours_All.rename(columns = columns, ... )
```

Yes this is more code and I should not have named my has columns but something else instead. So there is way for improvement. But it shows how you can use .format() for your call.